# Unterminated <fmt:formatNumber tag * Is this possible?

Tags: jsp, jstl

Hello all Im trying to do a series of when checks to concat two numbers I want to subtract and format.  Is this possible or there an alternative?  I get that error in the title.  Thanks

```
        <td><fmt:formatNumber value='${'
        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${columnB == 'MWS'}">'line.initialQS.quantities[0]'</c:when> 
        <c:when test="${columnB == 'SMC Unfunded'}">'line.expectedUnfundedQS.quantities[0]'</c:when>
        <c:when test="${columnB == 'SMC Funded'}">'line.expectedFundedQS.quantities[0]'</c:when>
        <c:when test="${columnB == 'MMC'}">'line.targetQS.quantities[0]'</c:when>
        <c:when test="${columnB == 'Current Scenario'}">'line.currentQS.quantities[0]'</c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
           </c:otherwise>
           </c:choose>
        ' - '
        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${columnA == 'MWS'}">'line.initialQS.quantities[0]'</c:when> 
        <c:when test="${columnA == 'SMC Unfunded'}">'line.expectedUnfundedQS.quantities[0]'</c:when>
        <c:when test="${columnA == 'SMC Funded'}">'line.expectedFundedQS.quantities[0]'</c:when>
        <c:when test="${columnA == 'MMC'}">'line.targetQS.quantities[0]'</c:when>
        <c:when test="${columnA == 'Current Scenario'}">'line.currentQS.quantities[0]'</c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
       </c:otherwise>
       </c:choose>
        '}'
        type="number"  maxIntegerDigits='10' minFractionDigits='0' maxFractionDigits='2' groupingUsed='true' /></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define variables for the values:

```
...
<c:when test="${columnB == 'MWS'}">
    <c:set var="bValue" value="${line.initialQS.quantities[0]}" />
</c:when>
...
```

Then do your calculations or formatting:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${bValue - aValue}" type="number" maxIntegerDigits="10" minFractionDigits="0" maxFractionDigits="2" groupingUsed="true" />
```

Comment: Very interesting my friend...im about to try that!